# Oracle Sql Group Avarage due to month

Tags: sql, oracle

I have one table like

```
ID    REFGROUP     YEAR   MONTH   VALUE
---     -----    ------  -----   -----
1       1000       2018    1       10
2       1000       2018    2       8 
3       1000       2018    3       12
4       2000       2018    1       6
5       2000       2018    2       8
6       2000       2018    3       1
```

I want to get avarage  month by month by group and year

```
ID    REFGROUP     YEAR   MONTH   VALUE
---    -----    ------  -----   -----
1       1000       2018    1       10
2       1000       2018    2       9 
3       1000       2018    3       10
4       2000       2018    1       6
5       2000       2018    2       7
6       2000       2018    3       5
```

Result will be above. For second month, get avg of first two month. For third month , Iw will be get avg of first three month group by refgroup and year.

I tried union  for each month but. It makes slow performance. I will make both 12 months for each year so. How can write sql query to do faster than I wrote. Mine takes 8 minutes which is too much

```
select 1 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=1 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 2 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=2 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 3 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=3 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 4 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=4 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 5 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=5 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 6 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=6 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 7 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=7 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 8 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=8 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 9 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=9 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 10 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=10 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 11 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=11 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
UNION
select 12 AS AMONTHH, REFGROUP,AYEAR, AVG(TOTAL) from BMS.FNC_W_PAYROL WHERE AMONTH<=12 GROUP BY REFGROUP,AYEAR
```

Comment: Search for analytic functions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use analytic functions here:

```
SELECT
    ID, REFGROUP, YEAR, MONTH,
    AVG(VALUE) OVER (PARTITION BY REFGROUP, YEAR ORDER BY MONTH) AVG_VALUE
FROM yourTable
ORDER BY
    REFGROUP, YEAR, MONTH;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Save my time. Thanks so much :)